# Excel sum data between 2 cells

Tags: excel, excel-formula, office365

I've been trying to use the data from a timetable to calculate the time it takes a vehicle to get from one point to another. The system has a 2 droplists to select a start and end along the route, those points are fetched from the table.

The plan was to use the chosen droplist option to calculate the time it takes to get from the chosen point starting point to the chosen endpoint by summing all values in the column between the 2 selected points (dynamic). All times are listed next to the stop.

[image: Table (data replaced with nonsense)]

I tried a lot of different approaches, all of which included the xlookup function.
Everything I tried so far just threw a wide range of errors, could someone explain to me which function(s) would be best to use in this scenario, and why?
*Preferably an example, instead of a ready-to-use formula.*

Comment: Are you fetching times based on index number (column 1) or name (column 2)?

Comment: If the former, then you can use a simple `SUMIFS()` and if the latter, try to use something along these lines: `=SUM(INDEX(Table1[DriveTime],MATCH("C",Table1[Stop name],0)):INDEX(Table1[DriveTime],MATCH("F",Table1[Stop name],0)))`

Comment: @JvdV One complication though…  that formula will include one too many drive times in the sum, as it includes the time it took to get from the previous stop to the starting stop.  In the example above, the drive time from O to R is 4 minutes and that formula will produce 10 minutes.  I think the first INDEX() will have to be modified to be `INDEX(Table1[DriveTime],MATCH(“C”,Table1[StopName],0)+1)`

Comment: If you want to use XLOOKUP() and your data set is such that you can add a helper column, you can also do this with a more readable formula by moving some of the logic into the data table.  If you have a column D that is cumulative time (in your example this would be 0; 2; 3; 7; 8; 9; etc) then the calculation is “XLOOKUP arrival time minus XLOOKUP start time”.  Adds a little readability, but is no more efficient nor shorter to type than JvdV’s approach.

Comment: I tried both versions of the suggested formulas, but I am running into the same errors as I did with my previous attempts. The formula provided by @JvdV throws a #name error, and the version suggested by Max R throws the #value error. I checked the sheets and formulas several times, but I can't see why it does this.

Comment: @Chris_NL, are all references correct? Is your table actually called Table1? Did you check headers?

Comment: @JvdV No, that one is completely on me. Since I'm using Excel with the language set on Dutch, I need to translate functions. No big deal, but I just failed to spot that `SUM` wasn't translate by me. I appreciate the help!